# PostgreSQL/pyscopg2 SELECT WHERE LIKE to search for string contained in any strings in db

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

new to psycopg2 and PostgreSQL and am trying to create a function to that, given a string, will search through all entries in my database that contain that string.

So far, I have:

```
def search(searchString):
    """ Let's user search by string for any snippet containing that string """
    logging.info("Searching for snippet by string: {!r}".format(searchString))

    with connection, connection.cursor() as cursor: 
        cursor.execute("select * from snippets where message like (%s)", searchString) 
        searchResults = cursor.fetchall()
        return searchResults
```

So let's say in my db I have a number of strings that contain the string 'testME'. At the command line, when I try `$ python myscript.py search 'testME'` to search for all strings in the db that have the word 'testME', on the entries in the db that are 'testME' exactly are returned and not any other entries with strings that contain 'testME'. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks like you aren't actually searching for anything, as '%%' just inserts a literal % into the query. I would try using '%%%s%%' instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. This might be what you are searching for: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/69-How-to-determine-if-text-phrase-exists-in-a-table-column.html
2. If there is no special need for this to be done with a function, you could do one of the following:

   - Let python do the difficult part. First fetch the table names

     SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables 
     WHERE table_schema = 'public';

   Using a tables name as a field name returns a string of all the 
   columns concatenated. So for all the fetched table names create 
   a query like

   SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE tablename ILIKE '%searching_this%';

   - You might also just do it by a system call within python. Dump the Database
     with pg_dump and grep for the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.execute("""
    select *
    from snippets
    where message like '%' || %s || '%'
    """, searchString
)
```

Comment: Could you add a bit of explanation as well? This popped up in the review queue.